# A good example of a simple crud Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I've searched github and just can't find a good example of a simple crud app that meets the following criteria:

- Rails 4
- simple crud operations type app (a todo list, contact manager, a blog/cms, etc)
- responsive design (preferably Bootstrap 3)
- AJAX crud operations
- a live demo url (preferably on heroku)
- clean, simple, and slick
- updated repo in the last 6 months

Anyone care to share?

Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome to write one yourself and put it up on github/heroku :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/todo-rails4-angularjs) is one, it's using angular js as well.

You can find the demo [here](http://todo-rails4-angularjs.shellyapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the code sample in the book “Agile Web Development with Rails” is great. Just go with it.

Comment: Which book would you suggest?

Comment: @JimJones book name added

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the "Depot" app is more of a traditional non-ajax type app (ie. posting from page to page).  I was looking for a best practice example of updating the page dynamically (or even with modals) for a more current UI experience.

Comment: @JimJones there is a chapter dedicated for ajax. But if what you want is a more current UI experience, then that book maybe not that suitable, as it is mainly about rails.